# Alt + left/right on my terminal moves my cursor word by word, however this does not work with backspace. Would there be a way to accomplish this?

Tags: terminal

I use karabiner-elements on sierraOS, but not sure if I can accomplish this in there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Terminal preferences → Profiles → *your profile* → Keyboard, map alt-backspace to ctrl-w (`\027`).

Comment: Thank you! I was wondering why this worked on other apps but not terminal.